# PushNotification -- no device found

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have  a hybrid app and having some issue seeing notification..

I get the error

com.ibm.pushworks.server.exceptions.PushWorksException: FPWSE0009E: Internal server error. No devices found

I running on Local MFP (eclipse -- V7.1).. I see the device in the worklightconsole and the app is install on my phone (Xcode->phone via USB) and I see the opt-in notification message.. However, I get the error when I tried to send a push..

I am using postman  and the restAPI
http://localhost:10080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/MyMobile/notifications/applications/myProj/messages

Here is the body of the post request

```
 {
    "message": {
    "alert": "Test message"
    },
    "settings": {
      "apns": {
      "badge": 1,
      "iosActionKey": "Ok",
      "payload": {},
      "sound": "song.mp3"
     },
     "gcm": {
        "payload": {},
        "sound": "song.mp3"
      }
  },
  "target": {
    "consumerIds": [],
    "deviceIds": ["166CB698-45C2-4C61-9074-248EA4F8AA8F"],
    "platforms": [
      "A","G"
    ]
  }
   }
```

---

Can you give some hints to solve this issue ..

Thanks

Comment: As a first step do a GET on the subscriptions:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_restapi_push_device_subscription_get.html

Check if this device id is indeed there

Comment: The same JSON works for me , in my local setup. Is it possible the device id you entered is wrong? With the current parameters within "target" you can get the error message only if the device id is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As Vivin mentioned in the comments, your device ID may be wrong.

> The same JSON works for me , in my local setup. Is it possible the device id you entered is wrong? With the current parameters within "target" you can get the error message only if the device id is wrong.